# Integral approximation with sums

Tags: matlab

I want to approximate the integral of the function x*sin(x) from 0 to 1 with:

1. Left rectangular rule
2. Right rectangular rule
3. Midpoint rule
4. Trapezodial rule

For the first one, I use the following peace of code and it works nicely

```
n=1000; a=0; b=1; f=@(x)x.*sin(x);
x=linspace(a,b,n+1);
h=(b-a)/n;
q=sum(h*f(x(1:n)))
```

But I'm stuck on how to proceed. For the first one, they use the formula

[image]

For the right rectangular rule, they use

[image]

Does the `x(1:n)` imply f(x_{i-1})? I'm especially lost on how I should handle the qsum for the third point, using the formula

[image]

For the 4th problem the formula that is used is

[image]

There are probably other ways to do this, but I want to apply the code I made for the first problem, and expand it onto the other problems.

Comment: Don't post the answer in the question, instead, post an **answer**. That way we keep Stack Overflow nice and structured like they intended.

Comment: Apologies for that, I will comply with your sugggestion in future posts. Thank you for the information!

Comment: It would be good to comply with it in *this* post too :) The current accepted answer doesn't actually answer the question. Answers should stand on their own merit, without future visitors having to trawl through comments (which have no version control and could be lost)

Comment: What @Wolfie is trying to say, is that it'd be nice if you posted the code you had in your question as an answer on this question. Self-answers are perfectly acceptable, and even encouraged if you managed to find the solution on your own. So for completeness of the post, and for the benefit of future readers it'd be appreciated if you post the code as an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second problem, right rectangular rule can be computed using the same linspace, but from 2 to n+1. For the midpoint formula, one has to compute the values in between the current linspace, as the formulas quite elegantly show it. For the trapezoid, one has to sum the areas of n semi-rectangles (no idea of the correct term), which are just the area of the rectangles, whose height is the average of the endpoints.

Comment: How can one calculate the values in between the current linespace?

Comment: 1) The right rectangular rule is more or less the same as the left one, but the height of the rectangle is calculated with the rightmost point, instead of the leftmost point. You divided the space into n+1 points including the endpoints to have n rectangles. Now just take the right edges, starting from 2, and ending to n+1. 2) You have a function f(x). That's how :D it is literally right there in the formula. You can calculate the average of the adjacent points of a vector with (x(1:n)+x(2:n+1))/2.

Comment: I understood 1) however isn't (x(1:n)+x(2:n+1))/2 used in the 4th method and not the 3d? it's not (f(x_i)-f(x_i+1))/2 in the formula but f(x_i+x_i+1), so it's a function of the average. (Updated the question to include the last formula)

Comment: I answered both at the same time, my mistake. The average isn't used in the fourth however, the fourth is for the averages of the **function** values, and calculating a rectangle that way. The midpoint rule is calculating the average of the x's and only then the function value.

Comment: Exaxtly, I've been able to correctly code task 1, 2 & 4 but I'm still having trouble in expressing the q=sum???? of task 3. How do I express the average of the x-values?

Comment: Wait, shouldnt it be 

´n=1000; a=0; b=1; f=@(x)x.*sin(x);
x=linspace(a,b,n+1);
h=(b-a)/n;
q=sum((h/2)*(f(x(3:(2*n+1)))))´

Comment: As I've written above: (x(1:n)+x(2:n+1))/2 gives the vector containing the middle points of the linspace specified as x. The statement sums two vectors elementwise, which are the points for the sides of the rectangle, and divides them, giving the average of the two coordinates.

Comment: So then this solves nr.3. Isn't it exactly the same for nr.4 then? For nr4 we have the average of the function values summed up. It seems as if the trapezoid rule is just the sum of the two left and right rectangular methods.

Comment: Strictly different. The third takes the average of the coordinates, then calculates the function value at that point. The fourth takes the average of the function values on the sides. Consider a single rectangle approximating the integral of x^2 from -2 to 2. Midpoint rule: 0*4, trapezoid: 4*4. Also, please mark the question as answered if you feel satisfied, so it'll be flagged.

Comment: Yes I will mark it in a sec. I'm just gonna post the codes for all 4 and I just need you to (hopefully) agree with me that they are correct. I at least get answers close to the actual!

Comment: Seems about right, and results are also similar. I'd say code well done.